# Navigation bar should stick to the top

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationbar

When I add a Navigation bar with Interface Builder to a Table View Controller it moves when the user scrolls. **Is it possible to make the Navigation bar static?**

With static I means that it sticks to the top of the application and when the user scrolls the cells are the only thing moving. I've got this working by embedding the Table View Controller in a Navigation Controller but this is not the best solution for my application because it adds other errors.

Comment: But it's the good way to do it! Create a UINAvigationController programatically and then add your TableViewController to it.

Comment: Not for me in this example. I forgot to mention that I use a Modal segue that flips the view. So I just needed a static bar. But rckoenes answer solved my problem. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, create a plain `UIViewController` than in its view place the `UINavigationBar`.
Under the `UINavigationBar` place a `UITableView`, now when you move the tableview the bar will stay in it's place.